# SAML authentication errors occur when logging into Bluemix

Tags: cloud, saml, ibm-cloud

When I try to log into my Bluemix account, the following error messages are generated:

```
https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/public/samlerror.jsp 

SAML Error
Timestamp: 2015-09-15T15:17:14Z

Error: SAML 2.0 Authentication Failed

Detail: FBTSML225E Token exchange failed.
```

Comment: doesn't work for me either. however, `cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and reported in the Bluemix status page. Bluemix team is actively working on it.
Please monitor Bluemix status page for updates:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

PS: In my case the error was intermittent. After shutting down and restarting my Chrome browser I was able to login.

Comment: @NarendraBokarvadiya146 You are welcome. Please kindly accept the answer if that solved your problem.